# Eclipse not working with JRE8

Tags: eclipse, lambda

I'm trying to use new feature of JRE8 like lambda expression but it causes an error. Is it because my IDE's version not supported? Here is my version of Eclipse.

> Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
>
> Version: Kepler Service Release 1
>
> Build id: 20130919-0819

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse Kepler does not support the new Java 8 features. The Eclipse Newsletter says there is scheduled to be an update to the Eclipse JDT (Java Development Tools) when Java 8 is released in March.

There is some more detail on the [JDT Java 8 Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java8)

Comment: Does it mean I can't use JRE8 for now??

Comment: You can use JRE 8 but not the new features in it. There is an early release Beta of the JDT updates described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_%28BETA%29)

Comment: this version of eclipse http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lambda-1984522.html works with lambdas